# Close all locations list or quick fix windows in vim

Tags: vim, gvim

Is there a way to close all locations lists and quick fix windows with a single command in vim/gvim?

Comment: Are we talking windows or buffers? Cause I'm looking for something similar but for buffers.

Answer (score 4):

```
:windo if &buftype == "quickfix" || &buftype == "locationlist" | lclose | endif
```

That will execute the :lclose command in all windows not displaying quickfix or location lists. I didn't have a set of location lists to test it with, so I tested with a different buffer type and it worked for that case.

You will probably want to make it a command or shortcut in your .vimrc as well.

Comment: `lclose` does not close quickfix lists, so this would not work for those.

Answer (score 4):

I map this to <F11>:

```
nmap <F11> :windo lcl\|ccl<CR>
```

Basically: In each window, run `lcl` (close location list) and `ccl` (close quickfix)

Answer (score 0):

```
:windo if &buftype != "quickfix" | lclose | endif
```

That will execute the `:lclose` command in all windows not displaying quickfix or location lists. I didn't have a set of location lists to test it with, so I tested with a different buffer type and it worked for that case.

Comment: Reread the question, he's asking to close all of the quick fix windows, not close everything but them.

Answer (score 0):

`:ccl | lcl`

#### Map it to `<Leader>c`:

`noremap <Leader>c :ccl <bar> lcl<CR>`

Comment: This will only close one location list: the one for the active window, if one exists.